# Не могу скомпилировать код Android studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, build, google-cloud-messages

при компиляции выдает "Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :app"
что это может означать?

Answer (score 0):

Это означает, что нужные пакет отсутствует и репозиторий для его загрузки тоже не настроен.

Решение можно [посмотреть на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811608/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services7-3-0).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло

Comment: Та же самая ошибка? Нужный пакет отмечен и загружен?

Comment: однако нет, данная проблема возникает после того как добавляю зависимости fire base messenging

Comment: эти зависимости добавляют такую строчку в gradle `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    } ` и почему она ему не нравится не знаю. пакет загружен